# Keyobard icon displayed in panel instead of language code in 16.10

Tags: unity, keyboard, 16.10

In 16.10, when several keyboard are installed only keyboard icon is shown in system panel, while in previous versions language code was displayed in instead.

Is there a way to get the settings from previous versions back? It helps a lot to see immediately which keyboard is active without extra clicking.